# Resize image with background fill for vertical and horizontal images

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to create an image gallery. I want to try this time with PHP Image Magick.

When a file is uploaded I want it to be resized to 1024x724. If the image is vertical (width < height ) I want it to be fitted in the center of the image and transparent background ( or white if not possible ) at both sides where should be blank, so the image can be always 1024x724 and the aspect radio to be kept.

Same applies if the image is horizontal ( width > height ).

Here is my code so far:

```
$img = new Imagick($targetFile);
$img->scaleImage(1024,724);
$img->setGravity(imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$img->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
$img->extentImage(1024,724,0,0);

$img->writeImage($targetFile);

$img = new Imagick($targetFile);
$img->scaleImage(150,150);
$img->setGravity(imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$img->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
$img->extentImage(150,150,0,0);

$img->writeImage($targetThumb);
```

Comment: Not sure about the rest of the command line parameters, but if you want web-viewable transparency, you have to go with .png or .gif. Jpeg formats do not support transparency.

Answer (score 13):

If I am understanding what you want correctly, you are already part way there.  Right now if you try to use a transparent PNG (source and destination), instead of a jpeg, it'll flatten the image and make the background solid white, and you do not want this correct?

What you'll need to do is determine if the image has, or might have, transparency and then set the background color to None. `-extent` flattens images, so to preserve the transparency the background will need to be `None` in those cases.  (And, as mentioned, you will of course need to use png or gif output rather than jpg as jpeg can't handle transparency.) Normally I would do simple extension checking as it's good enough most of the time, [but there are more detailed checks](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=18596).

```
$background = preg_match('/\.gif$|\.png$/', $thumbnailFilename) == 1 ? 'None' : 'white';
$edge = shell_exec("convert $imgFile -resize 1024x724 -background $background -gravity center -extent 1024x724 -quality 90 $thumbnailFilename");
```

I check the output thumbnail here because if you are outputting to a jpeg, regardless of the source, it's going to be stripped of transparency.  With this, if you provide `$imgFile` as test-transparent1.png and `$thumbnailFilename` as test-transparent1.sized.png, test-transparent1.sized.png should come out being sized to fit 1024x724 and padded with transparent pixels so the original image is centered.

==Edit for ImageMagick PHP class:==

First, in order to do a proportional scale, you'll need to set the bestfit parameter of scaleImage to true.  Additionally, it appears that extentImage doesn't use the gravity option at all when you use the API, so we have to use negative X or Y offsets to properly center the image on the new canvas.  Here's what my test script looked like once I got it working:

```
<?php
$targetFile = 'mizu.png';
$targetThumb = 'mizu.thumb.png';

$background = preg_match('/\.gif$|\.png$/', $targetThumb) == 1 ? 'None' : 'white';

$img = new Imagick($targetFile);

$img->scaleImage(150,150,true);
$img->setImageBackgroundColor($background);
$w = $img->getImageWidth();
$h = $img->getImageHeight();
$img->extentImage(150,150,($w-150)/2,($h-150)/2);
$img->writeImage($targetThumb);
```

== Update per comments: ==

For those who come to this answer and are using imagemagick after 6.5.7-8, this answer needs to be adjusted so that the extentImage x and y values are negative. you can see the caution note at [php.net/manual/en/imagick.extentimage.php](https://php.net/manual/en/imagick.extentimage.php) - courtesy of Jeff Richards

Comment: just one more thing. Can this be done with php class ?
I mean like $img = new Imagick('test.jpg');
and $img = resize to 2014x 724  something like this ? if u understand me

Comment: Yes, that should be doable with the Imagick class.  In particular, look at the manual entries for the `scaleImage`, `setImageBackgroundColor`, `setGravity` and `extentImage` methods.

Comment: OK I edited my post, it re sizes the image, but the ascpect ratio is not kept. Could you help me what I am wrong at ?

Comment: I wasn't very familiar with the Imagick class, so I put off getting back to you a bit.  Sorry about that.  Anyway, hopefully the example code I just editted into my answer is helpful.

Comment: Ok we are almost there, just the gravity s...t. It always makes the images 150x150 but the image is at the left even if i put $img->setGravity(imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);

Comment: That's because of gravity doesn't work like I'd expect it to in this case.  The math I included in my sample implements the centering in the extent.  At least it did in my tests.  What it does is set the starting coordinates of the extent such that the image will end up being centered.  We get the new smaller-sized image's dimensions and then shift the start of the extent left or up depending on the image's dimensions.

Comment: I had to investigate this issue myself in writing the sample.  I found this and tweaked it to center instead of south. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820754/imagick-setting-the-gravity-on-a-imagick-item

Comment: For those who come to this answer and are using imagemagick after 6.5.7-8, this answer needs to be adjusted so that the extentImage x and y values are negative.  you can see the caution note at http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.extentimage.php