# Set imagemagick text to middle

Tags: php, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I'm using imagemagick to put some text on an image but I'm struggling with finding a way to dynamically put the text bang in the middle of the box.

For bonus points, is there also a way to then offset it with a second command, i.e nudge it 50px right of centre. This is because usually I want the text to be in the middle unless they add a picture, then I need to make space for the picture too.

The text and font-size will be variable, but still needs to be centered.

This is my current code:

```
<?php
function process($inputdata)
{
/* Create some objects */
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'gray' );

/* New image */
$image->newImage(400, 300, $pixel);

/* Black text */
$draw->setFillColor('black');

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );

/* Create text */
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, $inputdata);

/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('png');

/* Output the image with headers */
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
return;
}
```

I tried adding this command, but it didn't seem to have any effect:

```
 $draw->setTextAlignment(\Imagick::ALIGN_CENTER);
```

The closest answer I could find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820754/imagick-setting-the-gravity-on-a-imagick-item), but it seems a bit long winded to have to calculate the size and then centre it that way.

Comment: What about setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER )

Comment: @Bonzo Hi. I tried that but it didn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -f
<?php
   /* Create some objects */
   $image = new Imagick();
   $draw = new ImagickDraw();
   $pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'gray' );

   /* New image */
   $image->newImage(400, 300, $pixel);

   /* Black text */
   $draw->setFillColor('black');

   /* Font properties */
   $draw->setFontSize( 30 );
   $draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER );

   /* Create text */
   $image->annotateImage($draw, 0, 0, 0, "Some funky text");

   /* Give image a format */
   $image->setImageFormat('png');
   $image->writeImage('result.png');
?>
```

[image]